# Grouping and visualizing master data with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, database, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

Let's say we group a multiple categorical variable with gruoup by and perform a Sum() operation on a variable.

ims_data2.groupby("Region").sum()

I want to visualize the resulting table as follows

sns.barplot(x="Region",y="productname MAT1" ,data=ims_data2);

However, in the resulting image, it visualizes the Y-axis of the graph by averaging. In other words, a visualization process based on the main table has been performed.
It's like the table made with this

ims_data2.groupby("Region").sum()

code is just an image.
If I wanted to see the real values on the y-axis, what should I follow? I can process the main table in excel, but this is not what I want of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `estimator` parameter:

> **estimator: callable that maps vector -> scalar, optional**
>
> Statistical function to estimate within each categorical bin.

```
sns.barplot(x='Region', y='productname MAT1' ,data=ims_data2, estimator=sum)
```

Comment: unfortunately; I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote :(

Comment: You can accept the answer :) Follow the link ;-) You can check the tick below the number of vote.